# #if __ANDROID__ is being omitted on Android device

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin, mvvm

I am using Cross-Platform Xamarin Forms with MVVM. In one ViewModel class, I wanted to use library that I got ready, in this library are #if statements that depend on the platform.

```
#if __ANDROID__
//some code
#elif __IOS__
//some code
#elif __WinOS__
//some code
#else
//some code
#endif
```

I am using Android phone or Android emulator, for Device.RunTImePlatform it shows Android, but it doesn't get into the Android if statement and goes to else.

What could be a problem, is there any place I can define these __ values?

Comment: do you have those symbols defined in your solution?

Comment: [Sharing Code Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing). In Solution Explorer, rt-click your class library, choose Properties, look for "Target framework". If it says "`.NET Standard ...`", then you can't use those platform-specific `#if`s. Instead, you put the Android code into files in your `...Android` project. In your class library, access it via a DependencyService.